# flutter Error "Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version" using flutter_local_notifications and location packages

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

Good day, i try to make an easy weather app with notifications for android and ios, for this I us base flutter app and libraries `flutter_local_notifications: ^0.5.1+2` and `location: ^2.0.0`, but using them both I get an error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A520F in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Flutter doctor output:

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590], locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (3 months ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\zande\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 32.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5124
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] VS Code (version 1.31.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\zande\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • SM A520F • 5200291746c1b485 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

My pubspec.yaml:

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.5.1+2
  location: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

My main.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Text('to 0')),
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0),
              child: new Text(
                  'Tap on a notification when it appears to trigger navigation'),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text("PayLoad"),
          content: Text("Payload : $payload"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutterapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I tried to use other geolocation libraries but often got errors like

```
D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver
```

for [geo_location_finder](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geo_location_finder)  library

or `WARNING: This version of device_info will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.`

for [geolocator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator)  library

What shoud i do to make my weather app?

Comment: First, migrate to AndroidX

Comment: How to make it ?

Comment: I added `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` to grandle.properities. The project is still buildes with each library separately, but with both it produces a new error:

Comment: `Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'. `
`> Android dependency 'androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable' has different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution`

Comment: Easiest way to migrate to AndroidX is to open Android project and use Refactor menu. Also your problem may be because on from your plugins uses AndroidX, while other does not, in this case you must fork problematic plugin and fix it to make it using AndroidX

Comment: Thanks, Android Studio automatically resolved my problem after writing android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true in grandle.properities and jpening android configurations separately/

Answer (score 19):

No joke, I recently had the same problem (and I was getting many complaints about various dependencies that were AndroidX, with -rc01 version endings), and various solutions for forcing a resolution strategy were not working.

I solved it by upgrading my gradle dependency in the android/build.gradle file: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' (I was previously on version 3.2.1)

Answer (score 12):

I met the same problem which is from androidX compatibility. the error message looks like:

```
android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath
```

I fixed it as below (if it's the same, ignore it):

1. In *android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties* change the line starting with distributionUrl like this:

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip

2. In *android/build.gradle*

> dependencies {
>       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0' }

- under *buildscript {* (if it includes kotlin)

> ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'

3. In *android/gradle.properties*, append

> android.enableJetifier=true
>
> android.useAndroidX=true

4. In *android/app/build.gradle*:

> Under android {, make sure compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are at least 28.
>
> ...
>
> testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

under dependencies {

> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
>
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
>
> implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

under defaultConfig {

> multiDexEnabled true

Hopefully, this helps!!!

Comment: This was very helpful. As Prakhar stated in another answer, it's probably the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1` version that is key to the solution.