# flutter: Build apk from flutter app is failed

Tags: flutter, gradle, flutter-layout

I am trying to build apk from my flutter app but i got this error :

```
Note: /mnt/Software/Linux/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-5.4.5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':keyboard_visibility:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:                                 
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     /home/tazik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4cfe0911440d16ca6e1ca90c791c61c2/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /home/tazik/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/4cfe0911440d16ca6e1ca90c791c61c2/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.



* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I googled and i find that compileSdkVersion must be 28. This is my build gradle app:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "net.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

But i still got error?

Comment: tried `clean`??

Comment: I did clean but i still got error @JohnJoe

Comment: How you build apk? What IDE are you using? Did your project able to run?

Comment: I am using android studio and yes project is able to run @JohnJoe

Comment: This is a complete error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Xj3MGKWMXz/ @JohnJoe

Comment: The error is not completed. From the exception,  it probably fail on  plugin `webview_flutter`. What version you using?

Comment: This is my all dependencies https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kTs8RzDFXS/ @JohnJoe

Comment: post the error after `The plugin webview_flutter could not be built due to the issue above.   
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...`

Comment: Those error was completed . https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/S3FjR6jxvb/ @JohnJoe

Comment: `The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try
using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.` You need to refactor it to `Androidx`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58125582/flutter-cant-buildl-apk

Comment: I selected migrate to androidx by android studo and also i added `android.enableR8=true` to gradle propertise and i remove webview library from popspec but still i got error. @JohnJoe

Answer (score 0):

You haven't accepted some android licenses. Please read flutter doctor output properly and run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

EDIT:

Also it seems you dont have libraries for linux.

```
On Debian/Ubuntu/Mint: sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6

On Fedora: dnf install libstdc++.i686

On Arch: pacman -S lib32-gcc-libs
```

Comment: I run you suggestion https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/D5gtB48wRm/ but still i got error @FahimMuntashir