# IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: null while login with twitter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, twitter-login

I am trying to login with **Twitter** when i used dependency **firebase_auth:^0.6.6** it was working perfactly and i fetch the user's **Profile picture** and the **Code** was

```
final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();
switch (result.status)
{
case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
var session = result.session;
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithTwitter(
authToken: session.token, authTokenSecret: session.secret); 
img=user.photoUrl;
}
```

but i migrated the app to **AndroidX** and this dependency was not compatible so i used **firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5** and this **code** was not working so i change the code to

```
final TwitterLoginResult result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

switch (result.status) {
case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
var session = result.session;

final AuthCredential credential =
TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(authToken: session.token,
authTokenSecret: session.secret);

FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
```

and this code is not working app is **Crashing** and showing the error

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(18829): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@70a4ccf
W/InputMethodManager(18829): startInputReason = 1
D/FirebaseAuth(18829): Notifying id token listeners about user ( D71yiiEX7ubSon4xxcddKlSydn72 ).
D/FirebaseAuth(18829): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( D71yiiEXccccccccKlSydn72 ).
I/zygote64(18829): Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=91KB
I/zygote64(18829): After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=68KB
I/zygote64(18829): Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=68KB
I/zygote64(18829): After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=68KB
I/zygote64(18829): Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
D/AndroidRuntime(18829): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(18829): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18829): Process: com.example.login_app, PID: 18829
E/AndroidRuntime(18829): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: null
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:291)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:291)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:291)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeSuccessEnvelope(StandardMethodCodec.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:225)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin$SignInCompleteListener.onComplete(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime(18829):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
I/Process (18829): Sending signal. PID: 18829 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Please can someone explain to me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with login task AND Androidx  [twitter_login_issue](https://github.com/roughike/flutter_twitter_login/issues/12)

Add this dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file and let me know this working or not?

```
flutter_twitter_login: 
  git: git://github.com/eudangeld/flutter_twitter_login.git
```

Same issue (question) [login_issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496368/execution-failed-for-task-flutter-twitterverifyreleaseresources/59559514#59559514)

Comment: @SanwalIjaz you tried this version of firebase_auth:   firebase_auth: ^0.15.2

Comment: Yes ,but its not compatible,it shows : "The current Flutter SDK version is 1.9.1+hotfix.2.
Because your_app depends on firebase_auth >=0.15.1+1 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.10.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed."

Comment: @SanwalIjaz upgrade your SDK like this
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"
I hope it will works