# Cannot Build Flutter App in Release Mode but works fine in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, firebase-admob

Below is the build error which flutter is giving , I don't know what i am doing wrong, my project is android.x supported still getting error, when i run it in debug mode it works perfect but as i build signed apk for release mode it starts giving me this error which is now really annoying me more than a day i am stuck in this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':thumbnails:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

   > Android resource linking failed

     C:\Users\Raja ahmed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c1da7862c7abb8e426855a3f78caf221\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.



     C:\Users\Raja ahmed\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c1da7862c7abb8e426855a3f78caf221\core-1.0.0\res\values\values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.





* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.



* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org



BUILD FAILED in 455h 48m 24s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           55.9s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
incompatibility.
Building plugin firebase_admob...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
The plugin firebase_admob could not be built due to the issue above.
```

pubspec.yaml

```
  splashscreen: ^1.2.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.3+1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  share: ^0.6.3+5
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  permission_handler: ^4.0.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.0
  path_provider: ^1.5.1
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.2.2
  flutter_html: ^0.11.1
  flutter_fab_dialer: ^0.1.1
  thumbnails: ^1.0.1
  chewie: ^0.9.8+1
  video_player: ^0.10.5+1



   assets:
 - assets/loading.gif
 - assets/video_loader.gif
 - assets/bg1.jpg
```

default config in build.grade

```
 defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.rajaonceagain.statussaver"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

its been now more than a day i am looking for this solution. I just update visual studio code nothing else , the day before i made a signed apk for release mode for other project and it worked perfect but dont know why today its causing this problem

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607026/7235539 and build your app again

Comment: already tried not worked

Comment: Try this solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32595#issuecomment-491639786. And in your case, you need to check all modules of android or search globally and change targetSdkVersion to 28 for all module Gradle. Then try to build app

Comment: Also try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561400/7235539 if above solution not work

Answer (score -1):

Please open android folder in Android Studio and you will get proper error in build window which is located at the bottom of Android Studio.
Please use following commands in terminal...

```
1. flutter clean
2. flutter run (To check running well)
```

then try with step to release build